# Negation "No + ... verb" and "but ..., rather ..." when emphasising

Tags: phrase-requests

If I want to emphasise a negation in sentence, say

> 1. Economy does not overcome crises but creates them
> 2. Economy does not overcome crises; it merely creates them

may I use a `No`-form to these statements? For example:

> 3. No economy overcomes crises; it creates them
> 4. No economy overcomes crises; it does create them
> 5. No economy overcomes crises; it merely creates them
> 6. No economy overcomes crises; rather, it creates them

Which structure of the sentence is better in English? May be there is some other version? By the way, should a comma be in front of `but` in 1. Different sources say the different.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to say here is that the use of the noun *economy* starts you with a potential problem, because of its dual use (a) as referring to the a particular economic area or country and (b) to the activity of *economising* or *thrift*.  Moreover *economy* in sense (b) is only the problem you have in mind in relation to whole **economies** in sense (a).

It may be partly because of that that the more common word used has been *austerity*.

There are many ways to skin this rhetorical cat.

But there is a second matter to be cleared up.  Do you really mean that for any particular economic crisis, economy does not solve it:  it actually creates it?  If so, I hope you can see that there is a contradiction embedded in the idea.  How can austerity create the crisis it was applied to solve?  It might make it worse; it might create new ones (wrecking public services, squeezing incomes etc...);  but it could not have *created* the crisis in the solvency of the banking system and national debt.

So I should not agree with any of your six options.  Or rather. I should stick with option (1): ‘not A but B’.  You might consider, for rhetorical emphasis, the following:-

> Not only does austerity not solve economic crises, it makes them worse
>   or
>   Austerity not only fails to solve economic crises, it actually creates/adds new ones
>   or
>   Does austerity solve crises in the economy?  No, it makes them worse/creates new problems.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. Seems that economy is not a good word here. I reproduced it by heart from some source
(I dont remember where) and that phrase was perhaps a joke there. 
So, what is at issue is just a structure of a phrase and the phrase itself should be short as possible
like an aphorism. You may replace it with some other, more appropriate one. 
E.g., something like `Industry does not use machines but creates them` (sorry, if poorly chosen example). 
All I care about is structure.

Comment: Well, In that case, you could say something like the following.  “Austerity does not solve <economic> crises: it makes them worse.”. The angled brackets enclose what I think ought to be there but does not have to be there.  This is only a personal opinion, though I have studied the likes of Demosthenes and Cicero in their original Greek and Latin (and, as a schoolboy, had to translate the oratory of the likes of Macauley and Churchill into Greek or Latin).  I think the use of ‘but’ gets in the way of the flow and so detracts from the emphasis.